# Troubleshooting Kubernetes tutorial fine parallel

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am attempting to work through the following tutorial https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/ . My problem happens at the very first step, trying to start up redis. When I run

```
kubectl run -i --tty temp --image redis --command "/bin/sh"
```

I create a new pod, however running

```
redis-cli -h redis
```

returns an error: Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Name or service not known

Comment: Hi, can you try to run `redis-cli -h $REDIS_SERVICE_HOST` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have `Kube DNS` setup correctly and what you got it's just a simple problem with name resolution.

If you look again at the [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/#filling-the-queue-with-tasks), they even mention you can encounter such problem:

> Note: if you do not have Kube DNS setup correctly, you may need to
>   change the first step of the above block to redis-cli -h
>   $REDIS_SERVICE_HOST.

So just instead of using `redis-cli -h redis` use `redis-cli -h $REDIS_SERVICE_HOST` and everything should work.